# JSON in a POST request is unsupported for Restlet

Tags: java, python, json, post, restlet

We're creating small project in which we have flask as a FrontEnd and restlet based WebService.

We try to send login data as a JSON from flask to restlet:

```
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        payload = {'username' : request.form['username'], 'password' : request.form['password']}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        req = requests.post(WEBSERVICE_IP + '/login', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        (...)
```

Flask based website is shouting about:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

We have no idea how to reconcile communication between flask and restlet.

**Edit (22-04 10:08pm GMT)**:
I found out that responce was:

```
<html>
(...)
Unsupported Media Type
The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method
(...)
</html>
```

**Edit (22-04 11:26pm GMT)**:
I'm still not sure why, but I supposed that it may be something with JSON format. After correcting my code so it will send correct JSON (said JSONLint), I still get the same messages. Anyone know how to create JSONObject in Python? WebService have method:

```
@Post("json")
public JSONObject verifyAccount(JSONObject dane){
```

**Edit (23-04 7:26pm GMT)**:
Ok. So we're almost sure that it's problem with invisible header. Can anyone confirm that header creation in python code here is correct?

**Edit (24-04 5:40pm GMT)**:
Problem is still actual. As some other suggested, I changed requests back to the urllib2. This helped with the first thing - "Value problem". Now browser is having

```
urllib2.HTTPError
HTTPError: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type
```

POST Request now:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        payload = {"Login": request.form['username'],
            "Haslo": request.form['haslo']}
        data = json.dumps(payload)
        clen = len(data)
        req = urllib2.Request(WEBSERVICE_IP + '/login', data,
            {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': clen})
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        response = f.read()
        f.close()
```

**Edit (24-04 6:20pm GMT)**:

[image: Wireshark captured POST request and it looks ok.]

Wireshark captured POST request and it looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Solution was easier than I would think.

Problem was on the WebService side. It was resolved by changing JSONObject to JsonRepresentation:

```
@Post("json")
public JSONObject verifyAccount(JsonRepresentation data){
```

Answer (score 2):

If `data` is a dictionary, Requests will serialize it. You want to pass a string instead:

```
import json

req = requests.post(WEBSERVICE_IP + '/login', data=json.dumps(payload), ...
```

Comment: Thanks, changed that but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Blender's point (which is a much more likely culprit), it's worth mentioning that content-type ought to be set to `application/json` rather than `json`.

Comment: Ok, but we just tried all possibilities we could make up: "json", "application/json", nothing..
Still no connection.

Answer (score 1):

To add on Hazards response, I had to edit `@Post("json")` to `@Post("application/json")`:

```
@Post("application/json")
public JSONObject verifyAccount(JsonRepresentation data){
```